# Hosting use sub-domains

Tags: subdomain, hosting, bluehost

I have a general question on hosting. I have two separate websites that I created for two small businesses. Each site will be assigned to a sub-domain. Now I'm considering hosting with BlueHost. They stated that I can create as many sub-domains as I want. My question is would there be performance issues as each site will have a separate amount of users??? I'm not concern with SEO performance as this site is only to be used by businesses.  My concern is as multiple users start using these sites how would this affect processing performance?

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a long time customer of Bluehost, I can say it wonot give a huge performance issue, 
but please keep in mind, whatever bluehost says you unlimit etc.., they have file count limit in shared hosting, if you reached the file count limit, they will warn you of closing your account or reduce the file limit,...

Comment: Thx for your response. So basically in future if I do have 20/40 websites with separate sub-domains I shouldn't worry about performance issues?? Even though each site my have roughly 30/40 people using it?

Comment: No I didnot say like that, however if those 20 or 100 sites are just static HTML page sites, then you will not have any issue. 
otherwise bluehost will warn you of utilizing higher cpu,memory processing power, since shared hosting is a server shared by many customers like you

Comment: Try to read the whole page of their privacy policy and terms and condition of unlimited terms they use.. you will have a clear picture

Comment: I see. So if I do intend on expanding with more business/subdomain with would be wise to have another hosting package to accommodate the increase in the number of users.